# Email рассылка с использованием python

Tags: python, email, sendmail

Делаю рассылку писем, но проблема в том, что в каждом письме видно кому оно еще пришло в поле "кому". Как отправлять индивидуально на каждый ящик?

Comment: в цикле на каждый ящик отдельно, других вариантов не знаю

Comment: [bcc](http://reisub.blogspot.ru/2011/05/cc-bcc-e-mail.html)